# In digest authentication, How does the server know which nonce it had sent in earlier call to which client?

Tags: rest, digest-authentication

In case of digest authentication server sends a nonce to client to encrypt its credentials. when the client subimts the encrypted string, how does the server know which nonce it sent to which client?
Are APIs really stateless if the server has to remember the nonce?

Answer (score 0):

The server knows because it's not client based, it's credential based. If a server remembers the nonce based on the TCP connection, it would indeed violate the stateless design.

Comment: Thankyou, but it is not entirely clear to me, is there a resource which shows diagrammatic flow of client-server interactions?